# Filtering in dplyr based on two non-numeric values

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data-cleaning

I am filtering a dataset and this chunk works fine:

```
    dwell <- rail %>% 
  filter_(Measure == "Average Terminal Dwell Time (Excluding Cars on Run Through Trains) (Hours)",
         Variable == "System") %>% 
  gather(Date, Hrs, -("railroad":"Sub-Variable"))
```

But I want to run the following code, adding a second option under variable:

```
dwell <- rail %>% 
  filter_(Measure == "Average Terminal Dwell Time (Excluding Cars on Run Through Trains) (Hours)",
         Variable == "System" & "System (U.S.)") %>% 
  gather(Date, Hrs, -("railroad":"Sub-Variable"))
```

But when I do this I get the folloing error: "operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types." I have tried swapping the & for | and that didn't work either. I feel like this is going to be a simple switch once someone tells me. Thanks!

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making an R question that folks can help with. That includes a sample of data, all necessary code, and a clear explanation of what you're trying to do and what hasn't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `Variable == "System" & "System (U.S.)"` for `Variable == "System" | Variable == "System (U.S.)"`. That should work.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `%in%` with `Variable` if we are trying on a fixed match for multiple elements i.e. > 1.  With `%in%`, we can include any number of elements as a `vector`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
rail %>% 
    filter_(Measure == "Average Terminal Dwell Time (Excluding Cars on Run Through Trains) (Hours)",
             Variable %in% c("System", "System (U.S.)")) %>% 
    gather(Date, Hrs, -("railroad":"Sub-Variable"))
```

---

Or may be more easier if it can be matched with `regex`

```
rail %>% 
    filter_(Measure == "Average Terminal Dwell Time (Excluding Cars on Run Through Trains) (Hours)",
         startsWith(Variable, "System")) %>% 
    gather(Date, Hrs, -("railroad":"Sub-Variable"))
```

---

In the OP's code `Variable == "System" & "System (U.S.)"` The `&` part is not evaluated as we need to either specify the 'Variable' twice, but that is still not correct because the column can't have two elements at the same position